# iPhone referencing my own word list for a Word Game

Tags: iphone, arrays, cpu-word

Boy, I've got everything down-pat save the word referencing. The game crashes because of the size of NSMutableArray.

What's the best way to create a word list that can be referenced without encumbering memory?

Thanks!

Comment: Just Curious. What is the size of your Mutable array? How many elements? Average size of elements?  How have you determined that it is the size of memory usage that has caused your problem?  Do you need to have the entire word set loaded into memory at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [SQLite](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)? Also, check out [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html). It's a part of iPhone OS 3